# Disable past Time angular bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, angular-bootstrap

I am using angular bootstrap datetimepicker. I want to make `$dates.selectable = false` for past date and time.

How can I do that?

Please let me know if you need the code example.

Comment: Better answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480646/disable-all-previous-dates-in-angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker), so you will want to use the [before-render callback](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker#before-render).

The code would look something like this:

```
function BeforeRender ($dates) {
  var activeDate = moment();

  $dates.filter(function (date) {
    return date.localDateValue() >= activeDate.valueOf()
  }).forEach(function (date) {
    date.selectable = false;
  })
}
```

The Read Me has an [example of a date range picker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker#create-a-date-range-picker-with-validation-controls) that does what you want.

Comment: For disabling past dates, `return date.localDateValue() <= activeDate.valueOf()`. But this disables the current date too. I want  users to enter current date but not past time. Like if the current time is `14 July 2:30 pm`, the user can select  14 July but not times before 2:30 pm. Can you update the answer to cover this scenario too.

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh I have covered your scenario too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61452476/9614476

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on its website ([https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) you can pass through your configuration object a "dateDisabled".

This is the html of the example:

```
<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <h4>Inline</h4>
    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
      <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="inlineOptions"></uib-datepicker>
    </div>

    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Format: <span class="muted-text">(manual alternate <em>{{altInputFormats[0]}}</em>)</span></label> <select class="form-control" ng-model="format" ng-options="f for f in formats"><option></option></select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="setDate(2009, 7, 24)">2009-08-24</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" uib-tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  $scope.inlineOptions = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: true
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    dateDisabled: disabled,
    formatYear: 'yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  function disabled(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
  }

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
  };

  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
  $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  $scope.events = [
    {
      date: tomorrow,
      status: 'full'
    },
    {
      date: afterTomorrow,
      status: 'partially'
    }
  ];

  function getDayClass(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  }
});
```

Pay attention on this row:

```
dateDisabled: disabled,
```

By passing this in your configuration object you set a function **disabled** as a handler for disabling the dates. So after a few lines you can read the disabled function:

```
// Disable weekend selection
function disabled(data) {
  var date = data.date,
  mode = data.mode;
  return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
}
```

The two parameters of the function are:

- date
- mode

date is a normal JavaScript date object and you can use all the [date methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) for this.

mode is the date mode, as you can see in this example you verify if mode is equal to "day".

So in this way you can simply disable a range of dates or custom days.

Comment: I think this question is not about the angular-ui date picker

Answer (score 0):

You can try to insert

```
startDate:"-0m",
```

this code disable all the dates in the past that becomes non clickables.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue recently, and after reading some stackoverflow answers, I came up with this code :

This takes care of day, hour and minute also.

```
    $scope.startDateBeforeRender = function($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate) {
        const minDate = moment().local().startOf($view).valueOf();
        for(let i=0; i < $dates.length; i++) {
            if($view === 'day' || $view === 'hour') {
                if (minDate > $dates[i].localDateValue()) {
                    $dates[i].selectable = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (minDate >= $dates[i].localDateValue()) {
                    $dates[i].selectable = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Html as :

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Time</label>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="data.dateDropDownInput"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.dateDropDownInput" data-before-render="startDateBeforeRender($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate)" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown2' }"/>
        </ul>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```