# disable all previous dates in angular bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am creating a project using angularjs. I am integrated the angulardatetimepicker from the link:

https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker.

Now I want to disable all previous dates from current date.
Here is my code:

```
 function beforeRender($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate) {
    var minDate = moment().startOf($view).valueOf();  
    for(var i=1; i < $dates.length;i++) {
       if(new Date().getTime() > $dates[i].utcDateValue) {
          $dates[i].selectable = false;
       }
    }     
    }
```

This code not disabled dates correctly

Comment: Would you create a fiddle for this please..

Comment: can't you just set min-date to the current date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minor Changes in your loop:

```
   function beforeRender($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate) {
    var minDate = moment().startOf($view).valueOf();  
    for(var i=0; i < $dates.length;i++) {
       if(minDate > $dates[i].utcDateValue) {
          $dates[i].selectable = false;
       }
    }     
    }
```

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Consider avoiding for...loops:

```
function beforeRender($view, $dates) {
  var today = moment().valueOf(); 

  $dates.filter(function (date) {
    return date.localDateValue() < today
  }).forEach(function (date) {
    date.selectable = false; 
  })
}
```

Comment: Doing this way disables the current day after the noon. 

Comment: You can, of course, use any date/time as the value for `today` above - use what ever value you need for your situation. You might try `var today = moment.utc().valueOf(); `

Comment: No, even this does not work , it keeps on disabling the current date too even after using `const today = moment.utc().valueOf();`